# python serial port

Tags: python, linux, pyserial

I want to communicate with my serial port in python. I installed pyserial and uspp for linux:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/1', 19200, timeout=1)
print ser.portstr       #check which port was really used
ser.write("hello")      #write a string
ser.close()             #
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poi.py", line 5, in <module>
    ser.open()   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyserial-2.5-py2.6.egg/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/tyUSB1: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/tyUSB1'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [help.....serial port programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051869/help-serial-port-programming)

Answer (score 6):

if you are working with linux, generally, serial ports are named `/dev/tty*` ; just replace the `*` with `s` and the number of the port like `/dev/ttyS1`.  I work with a arduino that communicates via usb-serial, and it's `/dev/ttyUSB0`.