# help.....serial port programming

Tags: python, linux, serial-port

I want to communicate with my serial port in python.  I installed pyserial, and uspp for linux.  Still, when I run the following code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/1', 19200, timeout=1)

print ser.portstr #check which port was really used

ser.write("hello") #write a string

ser.close() #
```

it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "poi.py", line 5, in ser.open() 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pyserial-2.5-py2.6.egg/serial/serialposix.py", 

line 276, 
in open raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg)) serial.serialutil.SerialException: 
could not open port /dev/tyUSB1: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/tyUSB1'
```

What should I do?

Comment: How do you get an error about /dev/tyUSB1 when you requested an open of /dev/pts/1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [python serial port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040151/python-serial-port)

Answer (score 7):

`/dev/tyUSB1` looks like a typo. Device nodes are normally called `/dev/ttyXXX`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open your second USB serial port, you want `/dev/ttyUSB1` instead of `/dev/tyUSB1`.